# Configuring Polkit to allow complete control remotely

Tags: remote-access, policykit

I have a headless server running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. It has been infuriating trying to deal with configuring various aspects of my server when I am not allowed to do so. Polkit has made the simple act of configuring a printer a nightmare, simply because remote users aren't allowed to do that, along with several other issues that I just don't have the patience to deal with. how can I configure it so that remote users have the same policies as local users?

Answer (score 1):

I needed the solution to the same problem on 21.04 and, after some
research, come up with this.  I'm pretty sure this will work on 20.04.
Note that it (probably) requires a reboot and that allowed users need
to me in the group "users".

```
gpasswd -a myuser users

cat > /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/52-headless.conf <<EoT
[Remote sessions exemption]
Identity=unix-group:users
Action=*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
EoT
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using xRDP via GUI (Not sure the problem you're encountering if you are using SSH only?).  Create one or both of these files and adjust accordingly.

#### Give permissions to run Thunar as admin via xRDP

nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/xrdp-thunar.pkla

[Authorize thunar for remote sessions]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.xfce.thunar
ResultAny=auth_admin_keep

#### --OR-- for Gnome/Nautilus

nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-remote-admin-allow.pkla

[Allow Remote Admin]
Identity=unix-group:sudo
Action=*
ResultAny=auth_admin_keep
ResultInactive=auth_admin_keep
ResultActive=auth_admin_keep